# Upgrade PHP to 5.3 on CentOS 5 and Plesk 9.0.1

Tags: php, centos, centos5, php53

I have a VPS that currently runs CentOS 5 and Plesk 9.0.1.

Right now the server runs PHP 5.1 but I really need to start running PHP 5.3. Is there a repository out there that would allow me to upgrade this without breaking the entire system?

Thanks

Josh Pennington

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think Plesk 9 works with PHP 5.3, partly because of the reliance on the deprecated safe mode.

If you want to take the risk, and have sufficient backups, I believe the remi repository contains PHP 5.3. See [here](http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2009/06/30/PHP-5.3.0-Released). If you end up doing a MySQL upgrade as well, make sure to do a full MySQL dump first, upgrade, then reimport the dump.

If you find PHP 5.2.14 would be suitable, you can use the atomic repositories:
`wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sh`
`yum update php`
You may find that php -v gives an error about ioncube. If it does, go into /etc/php.d/ioncube.ini (or similar) and change the 5.1 or 5_1 to 5.2 or 5_2 (I can't remember for sure). You may also need to remove php-sqlite2 before you can upgrade on a Plesk server, but you're unlikely to be using it (check dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I supply a yum repository with PHP 5.3 in, which fits in with existing PHP setups when upgrading. I can't guarantee that Plesk will be happy with it though unless they've updated it to support PHP 5.3

http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2009/06/php-530-on-centos-5/

There is also the Zend Server Community Edition, which you may find more suitable, however it doesn't provide packages under the same naming conventions, so you would have to switch between packages.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/